Using Transparent Huge Pages (THP) with shm_open and mmap on a Read-Only File in /dev/shm
I have a read-only file located in /dev/shm with an arbitrary size (not necessarily a multiple of 2MB or maybe smaller 120KB). I want to use shm_open and mmap to map this file into memory and then use madvise with MADV_HUGEPAGE to suggest the use of Transparent Huge Pages (THP).
I have already configured the following settings:
echo advise >/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/shmem_enabled
echo never >/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled

However, when I run my application, I observe that the process does not use huge pages. The ShmemHugePages value in /proc/meminfo remains 0.
Here is my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/sysconf.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file_path>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const char *file_path = argv[1];
    int fd = shm_open(file_path, O_RDONLY, 0666);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("shm_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct stat sb;
    if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1) {
        perror("fstat");
        close(fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size_t huge_page_size = sysconf(_SC_HUGEPAGESIZE);
    if (huge_page_size == -1) {
        perror("sysconf");
        close(fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    void *addr = mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        close(fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (madvise(addr, sb.st_size, MADV_HUGEPAGE) == -1) {
        perror("madvise");
        munmap(addr, sb.st_size);
        close(fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // TODO: do something for 10 mins or more
    // ... Read the file and do something.
    // After 10 mins or more.

    munmap(addr, sb.st_size);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}

Steps to Reproduce:
Create a file in /dev/shm with an arbitrary size.
Run the provided code with the file path as an argument.
Check /proc/meminfo to see if ShmemHugePages is greater than 0.
Expected Behavior:
The process should use Transparent Huge Pages for the mapped file, and ShmemHugePages in /proc/meminfo should reflect the usage.
Actual Behavior:
The process does not use Transparent Huge Pages, and ShmemHugePages remains 0.
System Information:
Linux Kernel Version: 5.4
CPU Architecture: x86_64
Additional Information:
The file size is not necessarily a multiple of 2MB.
The file is opened in read-only mode.
The system is configured to use THP for shmem with advise policy.
Question:
What additional steps or configurations are necessary to ensure that the kernel uses Transparent Huge Pages for the mapped file in /dev/shm?

Just for sanity checking, have you tried setting shmem_enabled to force? If that does not work something else is wrong

The program presented unmaps the test file and terminates very quickly after mapping it. Are you sure it's reasonable to expect to observe THP usage afterward?

@Botje  I have indeed set shmem_enabled to advise with the following command:
echo advise > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/shmem_enabled
The current setting is:
cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/shmem_enabled
always within_size [advise] never deny force
Would this setting affect the behavior of my application in any significant way?

@JohnBollinger Thank you for pointing that out. The example program indeed unmaps the test file and terminates very quickly after mapping it. However, in our actual application, the memory mapping persists for a much longer duration and is not unmapped until the program terminates.

Setting it to force would prove that you can do huge pages at all on that shmem file.

@Tefone, if the program presented does not provide a reasonable facsimile of the situation in which you are interested, then it is worse than useless.  Please present a bona fide [mre].

For test code you could just read 4 bytes at a time from the file and xor it with the previous bytes read. And sleep a few seconds afterward for good measure..

@JohnBollingerThank you for your feedback，I have updated it.

@BotjeThank you for your suggestion. I will try setting shmem_enabled to force and see if it makes a difference.
Additionally, I have a question regarding the alignment requirements for mmap. Specifically, do the file size or the starting address of the mapped region need to be multiples of 2MB? I couldn't find a clear statement about this in the documentation, except for the requirement for anonymous memory. Could you clarify whether this alignment is necessary for file-backed memory as well?

@Botje Thank you for your suggestion. I set shmem_enabled to force, and the results are promising:
ShmemHugePages is no longer zero.
The output of cat /proc/vmstat shows:
thp_file_alloc 2052
thp_file_mapped 3
thp_file_fallback 16
